# AppBar has left and right margin by default

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Store app BottomAppBar with a grid. For some reason the AppBar has some left and right margin which I don't want. Is this a bug in metro app or there is some setting missing in below code.

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.BottomAppBar> 
   <AppBar>           
<AppBar.Background>             
<SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0"/>            
</AppBar.Background>           
 <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"> 
           <Grid.Background>   
             <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.7"/> 
           </Grid.Background> 
           <Button Content="Hello"/> 
       </Grid>      
 </AppBar>  
 </common:LayoutAwarePage.BottomAppBar>
```

If you run the app, you can see that some region on the left and right side is not covered by AppBar( Or Grid). Why?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the default template of the `AppBar` control has some left and right padding.
You simply has to set the `Padding` property of the AppBar to `0`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Also setting margin to -10,-2 works, but anyway setting padding seems to be the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the left-right padding is there, so that controls are not drawn next to the edges of the screen.

Anyway, as @Mark says, just adjust the padding.

```
 <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar Padding='0'>
    <AppBar.Background>
      ...
```